# How to create a loading bar (looping)

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, loading

I would like to create a loading bar, which a line loads from left side to right side, I know how to make the CSS effects for it but it needs jQuery or JS to make it working. It never stops, just keep loading from left to right slowly. So looping basically.

Any idea?

Comment: Would you consider posting your code to show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/  Why not use something pre-built...
Also has 
http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate
just always showing motion or loading.